# How to create Vaadin multiline buttons

Tags: java, css, button, vaadin, multiline

I had the problem that I wanted to set a multiline text for a Vaadin button using Vaadin 8. 
However, I did not find a complete example on the Internet, so I would like to provide one here now if someone should have the same problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually you can do multiline caption in regular Vaadin Button as well.

There are two approaches

1. Use button.setCaptionAsHtml(true) and use `<BR>` line breaking.
2. Set definitive width for the Button, and enable word wrapping with CSS

In both cases you need to also set "height: auto" with CSS for the Button, otherwise lines will not be inside the button.

So for example

```
Button button = new Button("Multiple lines in a button");
button.addStyleName("multiline-button");
```

And in your theme mixin

```
.multiline-button {
   width: 125px;
   white-space: normal;
   height: auto;
}
```

Will result

[image]